# how to make json object from an element in json object with unique values in underscore js

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have a json Object as below

```
[
    {
        "MerchantName": "Fashion and You",
        "BrandList": " Nike, Fila",
        "MerchantImage": "Fashion-You-medium.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "MerchantName": "Fashion and You",
        "BrandList": " Levis, Fasttrack, Fila",
        "MerchantImage": "Fashion-You-medium.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "MerchantName": "ebay",
        "BrandList": "Nokia,HTC,Samsung",
        "MerchantImage": "ebay.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "MerchantName": "amazon",
        "BrandList": "Apple,Dell,Samsung",
        "MerchantImage": "amazon.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "MerchantName": "amazon",
        "BrandList": " pepe jeans, peter england, red tape",
        "MerchantImage, Fila": "amazon.jpeg"
    }
]
```

I need to make a json object with Unique BrandList as below in underscore.

```
[{"Nike"}, {"Fila"},{"Levis"}, {"Fasttrack"},{"Nokia"}, {"HTC"},{"Samsung"}, {"pepe jeans"}, {"peter england"},{"red tape"}]
```

Can i get the data as below instead of the above format, and the brand must be unique.

```
 brands = [{brand:"Nike",status:false},  {brand:"Fila",status:false}, {brand:"Levis",status:false},{brand:"Fasttrack",status:false}, {brand:"Nokia",status:false},{brand:"HTC",status:false}, {brand:"Samsung",status:false} ]
```

Comment: This is really easy to do with `_.pluck()` - look it up in the Underscore docs

Comment: Is your question really about JSON or about processing the data in JavaScript? Also note that your desired result is not valid JSON.

Comment: when i use _.pluck() im getting data as [" Nike, Fila", " Levis,  Fasttrack, Fila"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var col = [
    {
        "MerchantName": "Fashion and You",
        "BrandList": " Nike, Fila",
        "MerchantImage": "Fashion-You-medium.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "MerchantName": "Fashion and You",
        "BrandList": " Levis, Fasttrack, Fila",
        "MerchantImage": "Fashion-You-medium.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "MerchantName": "ebay",
        "BrandList": "Nokia,HTC,Samsung",
        "MerchantImage": "ebay.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "MerchantName": "amazon",
        "BrandList": "Apple,Dell,Samsung",
        "MerchantImage": "amazon.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "MerchantName": "amazon",
        "BrandList": " pepe jeans, peter england, red tape",
        "MerchantImage, Fila": "amazon.jpeg"
    }
];

var brands = [];
//get unique brands
_.each(col, function(i){
   brands = _.union(brands,i.BrandList.split(','));
});

//build output
brands = _.map(brands, function(brand){
    return { brand : brand, status : false};
});
console.log(brands);

//if you need json output
var brandsJson = JSON.stringify(brands);
console.log(brandsJson);
```

Source code http://jsfiddle.net/DvnvN/

Comment: I don't see way to do this without looping.

Comment: @nikhilreddy: Note that Nikolai used an array of objects as example. If you get your data as JSON, you have to parse it first (`JSON.parse`), apply the code to the result (an array of objects) and then convert it back to JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted the json object you listed is not valid. If you are looking for a way to populate an array of just unique brand names, you can use a few underscore functions -

```
var arr = ...;

function trim(str){
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

var mapped = _.map(_.pluck(arr, 'BrandList'), function(type){
  return _.map(type.split(","), function(brand){
    return trim(brand);
  });
});

var unique = _.uniq(_.flatten(mapped));
//outputs ["Nike", "Fila", "Levis", "Fasttrack", "Nokia", "HTC", "Samsung", "Apple", "Dell", "pepe jeans", "peter england", "red tape"]
```

- http://jsbin.com/eTIPoyU/1/

I'm not sure this is any easier to read then a simple loop and it creates several intermediate arrays in the process, but it gets the job done.